# ¿Cómo poner la condición del if dentro de un método? JAVA POO

Tags: java, poo, if

Buenas tengo que crear este programa :

Crea la clase PartidoDeTenis que contenga el resultado de los 5 set de cada jugador.

Crear
los métodos que devuelva el jugador que gano el partido. Considera los resultados en base
a las reglas del citado juego.

Mi problema es que no se como comparar los goles de ambos jugadores en los distintos set , intente poner un if y que su condicion sea jugador1.setUno()>jugador2.setUno() y en caso contrario gana el jugador2.Pero en eclipse me marca error y me pone :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También lo que hice fue poner un contador llamado `jugador1++` dentro el `if` y `jugador2++` dentro del `else` , as mientras gana el `jugador1` o `´jugador2` se va acumulando la cantidad de partidos ganados , pero no me funciona la condición del `if`.

A continuación les dejo el código :

```
public class PartidoDeTenis {

    private int jugador1;
    private int jugador2;

    PartidoDeTenis( ){
        this.jugador1= jugador1;
        this.jugador2= jugador2;
    }

    public int setUno(int goles) {

        if(jugador1.setUno()>jugador2.setUno()) {

            jugador1++;
        }
        else {
            jugador2++;
        }
        return goles;

    }

    public int setDos(int goles) {

        if(jugador1>jugador2) {

            jugador1++;

        }
        else {
            jugador2++;
        }

        return goles;
    }

    public int setTres(int goles) {


        if(jugador1>jugador2) {

            jugador1++;

        }
        else {

            jugador2++;
        }
        return goles;
    }

    public int setCuatro(int goles) {

        if(jugador1>jugador2) {

            jugador1++;

        }
        else {

            jugador2++;
        }
        return goles;

    }

    public int setCinco(int goles ) {

        if(jugador1>jugador2) {

            jugador1++;

        }
        else {

            jugador2++;
        }
        return goles;


    }

    public void ganadorDelPartido() {

        if(jugador1>jugador2) {

            System.out.println("El Ganador es el jugador 1.");

        }
        else {
            System.out.println("El Ganador es el jugador 2.");
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class PruebaTenis {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PartidoDeTenis jugador1 = new PartidoDeTenis();
        PartidoDeTenis jugador2 = new PartidoDeTenis();

        jugador1.setUno(1);
        jugador2.setUno(5);
        jugador1.setDos(2);
        jugador2.setDos(4);
        jugador1.setTres(0);
        jugador2.setTres(3);
        jugador1.setCuatro(0);
        jugador2.setCuatro(2);
        jugador1.setCinco(6);
        jugador2.setCinco(1);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedes llamar a un método desde dentro del mismo, a no ser que quieras usar recursividad y este no sería el caso. Si estas interesando en programar usando un paradigma orientado a objetos te recomiendo encarecidamente que separes los partidos de los jugadores puesto que son objetos de naturaleza claramente diferente, he codificado una pequeña solución al problema que has propuesto, también decirte que hay muchas otras soluciones y que si no quieres crear una clase jugador al menos necesitaras 2 variables para contar los sets de cada jugador y pasar a los 2 jugadores por parámetros a cada set, en vez de comparar los sets, hazlo con los 2 jugadores pasados por parámetro y según el caso aumenta una de las variables set en 1, saludos!!! , y si tienes cualquier otra pregunta no dudes en postear :)

public class jugador {

```
String nombre;
int setGanados;

public jugador(String nombre, int puntos){
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.setGanados = puntos;
}
public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}
public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
public int getSetGanados() {
    return setGanados;
}
public void setSetGanados(int puntos) {
    this.setGanados = puntos;
}
```

}

public class PartidoDeTenis {

```
private jugador jugador1;
private jugador jugador2;

PartidoDeTenis(jugador jugador1, jugador jugador2) {
    this.jugador1 = jugador1;
    this.jugador2 = jugador2;
}

public String setUno(int puntosjug1, int puntosjug2) {

    String frase;
    if (puntosjug1 > puntosjug2) {
        jugador1.setSetGanados(jugador1.getSetGanados()+1);
        frase = "Set para jugador 1, lleva " + jugador1.getSetGanados() + " ganados";
    } else {
        jugador2.setSetGanados(jugador2.getSetGanados()+1);
        frase = "Set para jugador 2, lleva " + jugador2.getSetGanados() + " ganados";
    }
    return frase;
}
```

public class main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    jugador jugador1 = new jugador("paco", 0);
    jugador jugador2 = new jugador("luis", 0);
    PartidoDeTenis partido = new PartidoDeTenis(jugador1, jugador2);

    System.out.println(partido.setUno(2,  1));
    System.out.println(partido.setUno(3,  4));
    System.out.println(partido.setUno(3,  4));


}
```

}

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias ya entendi :D Saludos!

Comment: Tengo una duda en la clase PartidoDeTenis , cuando declaras las variables jugador1 y jugador2 , que son de un tipo jugador , estoy acostumbrado a usar tipo String , int , long , double , float , char , etc , eso nunca lo vi , queria saber que era.

Comment: Amigo mirate este link https://www.abrirllave.com/java/declarar-y-crear-un-objeto.php
Al igual que creas objetos de tipos primitivos como int, double, etc
También puedes crear objetos de tus propias clases, definiendo los atributos que esta tendrá. A partir de hay la programación orienteada a objetos se vuelve realmente interesante :D, saludos